# .NET Core rounded corners for image

Tags: c#, image-processing, imagemagick, .net-core

I need to perform a few operations over images with .NET Core:

- Resizing
- Round corners
- Colored background for transparent PNG

I know it's not quite trivial on .NET Core as there are not many libs out there. I checked out [.NET Core Image Processing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/) post. I really like the API that MagickImage provides but I still don't know how to make rounded corners and background part.

I need code examples of the tasks above for MagickImage or any other .NET Core library. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I do not know Magick.NET, but the commands to do rounded corners can be found at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded and with shadow at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tidbits/image.php#round_shadow. I presume you can find the equivalent commands in Magick.NET. Resizing is simple in command line and I assume there is a similar command in Magick.NET. I am not sure what you mean by colored backgrounds for transparent PNG, but see -alpha background -alpha off at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#alpha_background.

Comment: CONTINUED: You can ask on the ImageMagick Discourse server for Magick.NET at http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewforum.php?f=27 and the developer for that API can probably help you further.

Comment: be careful when you create an MagickImage what are you going to do with that object finally are you going to show it to customer or you save it on a media. each of the scenario has its own solutions and concerns. for the background you can create  a bitmap map and fill it with the color you want and then composit it with the image magic object then you will get an image that has that color as its background (means the color will fill the transparent areas). if you need more detail I can write it here

Comment: the best library I think MagickImage while I have used it over years and now its in a good situations, they resolved lots of bugs and its now more stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. So I used MagickImage library:

```
Install-Package Magick.NET-Q16-x86
```

The code looks like this:

```
var mask = new MagickImage("mask.png"));
image.Composite(mask, CompositeOperator.CopyAlpha);
```

And here is how my mask looks like:

[image]

Note: mask's dimensions should be the same as image dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I used it in my case, hope it can help you:

```
var image = new MagickImage("iamge_path.jpg");
image.VirtualPixelMethod = VirtualPixelMethod.Transparent;
image.Blur(0, 8, Channels.Alpha);
image.Threshold(new Percentage(50), Channels.Alpha);
```

You can also refer to the image magic documentation on [rounded shapes and corners](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded).